# My tank fell and overturned. What to do?

Tags: planetside-2

I drove over a cliff by accident and it overturned during the fall. Should I just abandon it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a friend with another tank nearby, you can try pushing the tank either into an obstacle or down a cliff and hope that it turns around again. However, the more likely result is that it blows up and probably takes your friends tank with it.

The best solution is to just abandon it and pull another one.

Comment: Yep, deconstructing it is the best choice, doesn't it also give a tiny bit of the resource back aswell?

Comment: @Lyrion That is a common false myth, you do not get resources back. I made a video proof of it for a comment for this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108047/is-there-a-place-to-park-vehicles  ; I don't want to go around putting the link everywhere, so just check the comment there.